# Program to code zigzag matrix

Tags: c, matrix

Recently, I encountered with a problem that asked me to write a dynamic code that print `n x n` matrix in a `zigzag` pattern. Please help me with the code to get the output stated below.

Output:

```
rows: 5
cols: 5

 1  2  3  4  5

10  9  8  7  6

11 12 13 14 15

20 19 18 17 16

21 22 23 24 25
```

The Code that I've tried so far is in static:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int arr[3][3]={1,2,3,
         4,5,6,
         7,8,9};

int i, j, k;

for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    printf("%d",arr[0][i]);
}
    printf("\n");
for(j=2; j>=0; j--){
    printf("%d",arr[1][j]);
}
printf("\n");
for(k=0; k<3; k++){
    printf("%d",arr[2][k]);
}
printf("\n");
return 0;

}
```

Now I want the same thing to be done with the user stating rows and columns of an array..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int rows, columns;
    int rowCount, columnCount, count = 0;

    printf("Please enter rows and columns:\n>");
    scanf("%d %d", &rows, &columns);


    for(rowCount = 0; rowCount < rows; rowCount++) {

        for(columnCount = 1; columnCount <= columns; columnCount++) {

            if(count % 2 == 0)
                printf("%4d " , (columnCount+(rowCount*columns)));
            else
                printf("%4d " , ((rowCount+1)*columns)-columnCount+1);    

        }
        count++;
        printf("\n");
    }


    return 0;

}
```

Input:

```
5 5
```

Output:

```
 1  2  3  4  5
10  9  8  7  6
11 12 13 14 15
20 19 18 17 16
21 22 23 24 25
```

Comment: The program runs perfectly fine for 5x5 matrix.. But when I try to run 3x3 or 4x4 matrix, the result is different. It skips some of the numbers in series while giving output of matrix in zigzag pattern.

Comment: @Android7 I'll take a look (sry didn't test it with 3x3)

Comment: @Android7 So updated it! Hope it works for you now :D

Comment: The edit now works fine for same number of nxn(3x3) matrixs. Now if you would like to improve the program further, then i got an issue where when i try 3x4 or 4x5 matrix, the output is not in series.

Comment: @Android7 3x4 and 4x5 works fine for me! copyed the code again in the answer! test it again.

Comment: Perfect!! Actually I was running the previous program.. Your help making me learn the C program exponentially. It's working fine in the horizontal zigzag pattern, Now if i want the same thing to happen vertically. Would you be able to do that. If you want you can mail me the program at garaisomnath@gmail.com

Comment: @Android7 I can try it! You can create a new question an i answer it!

Comment: @Android7 Also if you make a new question please explain how the output should look like

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27124960/program-to-code-zigzag-matrix-vertically

Answer (score 0):

> Simple **dynamic** logic with **k** variable

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int i,j,k=1,row,col;

    printf("Enter row and col \n>");
    scanf("%d %d", &row, &col);

    for (i = 1; i <=row; i++) 
        {
            for (j = 1; j <=col; j++) 
            {
                if(i%2==0) k--; 

                printf("%4d",k); // it have to be in center of both condition 

                if(i%2!=0) k++; 
            }
            k=k+col;
            printf("\n");

        }
    return 0;
}
```

> Input :

```
7 7
```

> Output :

```
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
  14  13  12  11  10   9   8
  15  16  17  18  19  20  21
  28  27  26  25  24  23  22
  29  30  31  32  33  34  35
  42  41  40  39  38  37  36
  43  44  45  46  47  48  49
```