# Program to code zigzag matrix vertically

Tags: c, matrix

I am writing a dynamic code that print n x n matrix in a zigzag pattern. Please help me with the code to get the output stated below:

The Code that I've tried so far with help of Rizier123 is in horizontal zigzag pattern:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int rows, columns;
    int rowCount, columnCount, count = 0;

    printf("Please enter rows and columns:\n>");
    scanf("%d %d", &rows, &columns);


    for(rowCount = 0; rowCount < rows; rowCount++) {

        for(columnCount = 1; columnCount <= columns; columnCount++) {

            if(count % 2 == 0)
                printf("%4d " , (columnCount+(rowCount*columns)));
            else
                printf("%4d " , ((rowCount+1)*columns)-columnCount+1);

        }
        count++;
        printf("\n");
    }


    return 0;

}
```

Input:

```
5 5
```

Output:

```
 1  2  3  4  5
10  9  8  7  6
11 12 13 14 15
20 19 18 17 16
21 22 23 24 25
```

I want the same zigzag pattern output but vertically..

**EDIT**

Expected output:

```
1 10 11 20 21 30
2  9 12 19 22 29
3  8 13 18 23 28
4  7 14 17 24 27
5  6 15 16 25 26
```

Comment: Start with creating the algorithm+code for the first column.

Comment: @Wimmel Your tips is indeed helpful for starter like me.

Comment: That is the issue with being too helpful... people just copying someone's else program without understanding it and learning nothing. You are just asking someone else to do your job (no, thanks). Show us some work on your own and which trouble have you found, and you might get some help.

Comment: @SJuan76 I agree with you and views that providing direct solution might make a person dependent and they just copy paste rather attempting to work hard on the problem. But some people like me are very new to programming, I have tried to learn a lot from textbooks but it takes very long to develop the skills to solve a problem, but with the solution for some problem(not always) will definitely allows us to learn the art of programming at exponential rate. You dont need to be very harsh on a newbie..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int rows, columns;
    int rowCount, columnCount;

    printf("Please enter rows and columns:\n>");
    scanf("%d %d", &rows, &columns);


    for(rowCount = 0; rowCount < rows; rowCount++) {

        for(columnCount = 0; columnCount < columns; columnCount++) {

          if(columnCount % 2 == 0)
                printf("%4d " , rows*(columnCount)+rowCount+1);
            else
                printf("%4d " , (rows*(columnCount+1))-rowCount);    

        }

        printf("\n");
    }


    return 0;

}
```

Input:

```
5 5
```

Output:

```
1  10  11  20  21
2   9  12  19  22
3   8  13  18  23
4   7  14  17  24
5   6  15  16  25
```

Comment: That's not the expected output.

Comment: That's more like it :D

Comment: @UniCell He edited his question! And now i updated it :D

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks once again for being of great help. This is surely helping me to learn the art of manipulating the for loop and  the conditions to meet the desired output.

Comment: what if i want to print `25  24  23  22  21                                                                              -                                16  17  18  19  20                                                                       -                                15  14  13  12  11                                                                           -                                 6    7    8    9   10                                                                                -                                 5    4    3     2    1` in matrix format